# NSXMLDocument objectByApplyingXSLT with XSL Include

Tags: xml, cocoa, xslt

I'm having some trouble with XSL-processing when there are stylesheets that include other stylesheets relatively.

(the XML-files may be irrelevant but are included for completeness - code is at the bottom).

Given the XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<famous-persons>
<persons category="medicine">
  <person>
   <firstname> Edward   </firstname>
   <name>      Jenner   </name>
  </person>
</persons>
</famous-persons>
```

and the XSL-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:include href="included.xsl" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

referencing this stylesheet in the same directory called included.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <html><head><title>Sorting example</title></head><body>
    </body></html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

how can I make it that the following code fragment:

```
NSError *lError = nil;
NSXMLDocument *lDocument = [ [ NSXMLDocument alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                        [ NSURL URLWithString: @"file:///pathto/data.xml" ]
                                    options: 0
                                    error: &lError ];

NSXMLDocument *lResult = [ lDocument objectByApplyingXSLTAtURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"file:///pathto/style.xsl" ]
                                    arguments: nil
                                    error: nil ];
```

does not give me the error:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "included.xsl"
compilation error: element include
xsl:include : unable to load included.xsl
```

I have been trying all sorts of options. Also loading XML documents with NSXMLDocumentXInclude beforehand does not seem to help. Specifying the absolute path to the to-be-included XSL file works flawlessly.

Is there any way to make the XSL processing so that a stylesheet can include another stylesheet in its local path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. In the end I wrote the `SWXSLTransform` class which is included in my SWXMLMapping framework: https://github.com/oriontransfer/SWXMLMapping

The main issue is that under the hood, `-[NSXMLDocument objectByApplyingXSLTAtURL:...]` is actually not passing the URL to `libxslt`. Instead, it loads the data pointed at that URL, and feeds the data into `libxslt` without any base URI. Because of this, the current working directory becomes the base URI - you can use `<xsl:include href="...">` where href is relative to the current working directory... Not very useful!

As far as I can tell, the `NSXMLDocument` interface is completely broken, and there doesn't seem to be any way to fix it. I've filed a bug report.